# Bind to host's css property (and not class)

Tags: html, css, angular, dom, typescript

How do I get a css property and not a class in Angular2?

I have the following code:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    templateUrl: 'views/masterpage.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    @HostBinding('attr.class') hostClass = "sticky-header sidebar-open"; // Works, but not what i want
    @HostBinding('style.position') hostPosition:string; // Does not work

    sidebarToggle() {
        this.sidebarCollapsed = !this.sidebarCollapsed;
        this.hostClass = (this.sidebarCollapsed ? "sidebar-collapsed" : "sticky-header sidebar-open");

        // Here I wanna check what is the 'position' property of my host (body). 
        // See "style-responsive.css"
    }
}
```

style-responsive.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, the page will add the position relative to the body whenever the user shrinks the window.

I just wanna get this information in my Angular component. hostPosition should be undefined if window is larger than 1024px and 'relative' if smaller than that.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@HostBinding()` is not for reading, only for writing.

You can use

```
@HostBinding('style.position') hostPosition:string;
```

to get the value of `hostPosition` assigned to the elements `style.position`, but **not** to read the current `style.posotion`.

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {
  console.log(elRef.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
  console.log(elRef.nativeElement.offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't quite answer my question. So you mean it's not possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: What do you want? You can of course read `nativeElement.style.position` instead of `nativeElement.offsetLeft`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to get the style of the element.  `this.elRef.nativeElement.style.position` is always empty (""), because that seems to get what is in the style property and not in some class that's affecting the element.
I have tried also to check `document.body.style.position`, but it's the same thing, what I need is something like the jQuery function `$("body").css("position")`

Comment: Just found the solution using `window.getComputedStyle`. I edited the post adding that and marked as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will work, however is worth to try:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
      handleClick(event: Event) {
       //Do something when resize window
      }
```

That should be notified when your window is resized and get current info your body position